# Angular 6 reactive forms, synchronous cross field validation

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

**@angular/forms: 6.1.7**

I'm trying to create a custom validator that checks 2 **formControl**'s for inconsistent.

When following the [official angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#cross-field-validation) I get a error when inputting value to one of the 2 forms:

```
Uncaught Error: Expected validator to return Promise or Observable.
    at toObservable (forms.js:596)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at FormControl.asyncValidator (forms.js:584)
    at FormControl.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.AbstractControl._runAsyncValidator (forms.js:2454)
    at FormControl.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.AbstractControl.updateValueAndValidity (forms.js:2427)
    at FormControl.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormControl.setValue (forms.js:2764)
    at updateControl (forms.js:1699)
    at DefaultValueAccessor.onChange (forms.js:1684)
    at DefaultValueAccessor.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.DefaultValueAccessor._handleInput (forms.js:741)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (ChangePasswordComponent.html:13)
```

It looks like angular is trying to fins a **asyncValidator** in this case, and not the **sync** version that i expect.

Worth to mention is that i also have tried to return a `Observable<ValidationErrors | null>` that gives me the same error output.

**Validator:**

```
import { FormGroup, ValidationErrors, ValidatorFn } from '@angular/forms';

export const passwordMatchValidator: ValidatorFn = (control: FormGroup): ValidationErrors | null => {
  const password = control.get('password');
  const confirmPassword = control.get('confirmPassword');

  if (!password || !confirmPassword) {
    return null;
  }

  return password === confirmPassword ? null : { passwordMismatch: true };
};
```

**Implementation:**

```
  this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group(
      {
        password: ['', Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)],
        confirmPassword: ['', Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]
      },
      {
        validators: passwordMatchValidator
      }
```

### Question

How do i create a custom synchronous cross field validator?

### Question on the side

Is it possible to pass in the *formControl names* to the function instead of hard coding them?

### UPDATE: Final solution

```
import { FormGroup, ValidationErrors, ValidatorFn } from "@angular/forms";

export const matchValidator = (firstControlName: string, secondControlName: string): ValidatorFn => {
  return (control: FormGroup): ValidationErrors | null => {
      const firstControlValue = control.get(firstControlName).value;
      const secondControlValue =  control.get(secondControlName).value;
      if (!firstControlValue || !secondControlValue) {
          return null;
      }
      return firstControlValue === secondControlValue ? null : { mismatch: true };
  }
};
```

**Implementation:**

```
this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group(
      {
        password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]],
        confirmPassword: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]],
        currentPassword: ['', Validators.required]
      },
      {
        validator: matchValidator('password', 'confirmPassword')
      }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the documentation, you should pass `validator` property into `extra` param for `group` function in `FormBuilder`. See [the docs](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormBuilder#group). Second problem is that you should pass an array as second argument when creating form control and you set the validators directly with `formBuilder`:

`password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]]`

because currently the `minLength` validator is treated as `asyncValidator` as it is third argument.

**Side question**

You could create a validator factory function which creates the validator for you and takes 2 controls:

`export const passwordMatchValidator = (passwordControl: AbstractControl, confirmPasswordControl: AbstractControl): ValidatorFn => {
    return (control: FormGroup): ValidationErrors | null => {
        const password = passwordControl.value;
        const confirmPassword = confirmPasswordControl.value;
        if (!password || !confirmPassword) {
            return null;
        }
        return password === confirmPassword ? null : { passwordMismatch: true };
    }
};`

and usage:

`passwordMatchValidator(this.formGroup.get('password'),this.formGroup.get('confirmPassword'))`;

or the factory function could just take string params instead of controls and extract the form controls itself.

Comment: Thank you so much for this!